# Add new column to a new dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: r

I want to append a new column with `173` `rows` to a new empty dataframe and I have got this error

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  les arguments impliquent des nombres de lignes différents : 173, 0
```

My expected output is a dataframe "dataint" with all class columns integer from my original dataframe "data"

```
dataint<-data.frame()
    for (i in 1:ncol(data))
      if(class(data[[i]])=="integer")
        {   dataint<-cbind(dataint,data[[i]])
       }
```

Comment: You need to update your question with your data and what is the expected output. Otherwise, it will receive many down votes.

Comment: Just do `libarary(dplyr); data %>% select_if(is.integer)`

Comment: or `data[sapply(data, is.integer)]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `select_if` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  select_if(is.integer)
```